# Floating multiple elements in a container

Tags: css, css-float

**I got this:**

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/urodit/1/edit).

**And I would like this result:**

[image]

**I got this far:**

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/urodit/2/edit).

Comment: See my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Comment: see my updated fiddle with variable width and without any issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways you can do this in a flexible way.  Both remove the need for floats (and clearing floats) and neither requires JavaScript to achieve.

The first is to use flexbox.  The advantage here is that if there isn't enough room for the elements to fit comfortably on one row, they'll adapt.  The down side is that IE10 is the first version of IE to support it.  As a fallback, you'll need to use `display: inline-block` on each of the elements with `flex` applied to them.

http://jsfiddle.net/n4Yzc/7/

```
.always-visible {
    display: flex; /* prefixed attribute: -moz-flex, -webkit-flex */
    align-items: stretch; /* prefixed property: -moz-align-items, -webkit-align-items */
    flex-flow: row wrap; /* prefixed property */
}

.toggle-me {
    background-color: green;
    flex: 1 1 5em; /* prefixed property */
} 

.name-mail {
    background-color: red;
    flex: 1 1 8em; /* prefixed property */
}

.description {
    background-color: yellow;
    flex: 2 1 50%; /* prefixed property */
}

.favourite-food {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

The second is to use the `display: table` properties.  This solution is well supported (IE8+), but it ends up looking squished on narrower devices.

http://jsfiddle.net/n4Yzc/5/

```
.always-visible {
    display: table;
}

.toggle-me {
    background-color: green;
    display: table-cell;
} 

.name-mail {
    background-color: red;
    display: table-cell;
}

.description {
    background-color: yellow;
    display: table-cell;
}

.favourite-food {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Comment: The second approach is quite elegant, nice! I'm putting a min-width on the body to avoid extreme squishing.

Comment: It might be better to use media queries so that the `display: table` properties are only set if the window has a `(min-width: 40em)` or something like that.  That way it displays vertically for narrow devices, horizontally for wider devices.

Answer (score 0):

See the fiddle for desired output: http://jsfiddle.net/n4Yzc/2/

```
.toggle-me {
background-color: green;
  float:left;
    height:100px;
}

.name-mail {
background-color: red;
    float:left;
    height:100px;
}

.description {
background-color: yellow;
    float:left;
    width:67%;
}

.favourite-food {
background-color: orange;
}
```

**Updated fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/n4Yzc/6/

Width variable width of **description div** on basis of **toggle-me and name-mail divs.**

Comment: The problem with this is, that the solution works with a magic number (67%). What happens, when the email string is longer than the given example (which could happen easily?).

Comment: I'd prefer not to use javascript for this though.

Answer (score 0):

adjust height of  `toggle-me, name-mail` and `description` class like the following

```
 .toggle-me {
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
      height:150px;
    }

    .name-mail {
    background-colo

        r: red;
        float:left;
          height:150px;
        }

        .description {
        background-color: yellow;
          height:150px;
        }

        .favourite-food {
        background-color: orange;
        }
```

Comment: If you set a static height on text elements, you're going to end up with overflow issues if the text is longer than you planned for.  This looks like some sort of profile page element, potentially user edited.